# Mandelbrot's Coastline Paradox Formula

Tags: notation, fractals

I was reading Benoit Mandelbrot's [paper on the coastline paradox](https://users.math.yale.edu/~bbm3/web_pdfs/howLongIsTheCoastOfBritain.pdf), where he lays out a formula for determining the length of a coastline/border/self-similar curve:

L(G)=F*G<sup>1-D</sup>

Where *G* represents the length of the segments used to measure the coastline, *D* represents the Hausdorff Dimension of the shape/coastline being measured, and *F* represents a "positive constant prefactor".

My question is, what is constant that *F* represents, and how can I find it? Mandelbrot doesn't seem to elaborate on this, and nowhere on the web that I've found explains what *F* represents.